# How to draw a circle colorpicker with HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, css

How can I implement the circle color picker like this:
https://monosnap.com/file/NytBSoYK8V5XyTXVtG7dOuwoQlca5l.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried any plugin for it?

Comment: Thanks, but I only want to implement it by using html5/css3 and javascript

Comment: So it will already be using JS/CSS and obviously HTML

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use jquery or any plugin as well :(

Answer (score 4):

Why reinvent the wheel?
[plugin wheelcolorpicker](http://files.jar2.net/jquery/wheelcolorpicker/example-v2/example.html);
[plugin colorwheel](https://jweir.github.io/colorwheel/);
[google wheel color](https://www.google.ro/search?q=wheel+color+plugin+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gws_rd=cr&ei=jX0JWZbMCevAgAaRpJDoCA)

Comment: thank for your help, but I can't use jquery, or any plugin :( just make it by using pure html/css and javascript

Comment: Would something without jquery be ok? lilke [plugin](http://www.daviddurman.com/flexi-color-picker/)